# iPhone stuck on loading even though requests has been loaded

Tags: iphone

We have an issue with two of our websites, where iPhone won't load the page if there's too many pictures on the page. All images are cropped and is lazy loaded. Issue only occurs on iPhones

Websites are built in Umbraco 10, uses AzureBlob storage for images and is on the same server. We have websites built exactly like this without any issues.

Link to issue: https://scu.dk/om-scu/find-medarbejder/

Link to similar issue: https://karrierebyviborg.dk/uddannelser/

Link to working website: https://skibelund.s2.cruit.io/om-skolen/medarbejdere/

**Testing on Browserstack:**

This shows all requests have been loaded (except a css file)

[image]

This shows the iPhone is stuck on loading screen, even though the document is loaded + all the other requests has been loaded.

[image]
Does anybody have any idea where I could continue to debug this?

Comment: Update: Even chunking the images in batches and waiting 5 seconds will cause the website to break in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this:

We finally figured out what the issue was that, on the columns with images, we had a `filter: drop-shadow` CSS property:

```
filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05));
```

Turning this off or replacing it with a `box-shadow` property fixed the issue.

This seems like a bug on iOS devices: We have tested on multiple other websites – every time this property is present on an element, iOS devices the page slows down.